# Extracting Bitcoin historical ticker data by setting up Bitcoin Node?

Tags: bitcoin-core, currencies, full-node, bitcore, node.js

How do I extract the **ticker data** (historical values such as **day price, day open, day close** etc) by setting up a Bitcoin Node? 
Bitcoin Node is setup using [Bitcore.io](https://bitcore.io/api/)

All blocks are syncing right now, but I don't really know how to get data?

Stack I use is Node.js with MongoDB

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The Bitcoin Node is part of the blockchain network. It has nothing to do with markets and trading, and has no concept of a price. As far as the node is concerned, 1 Bitcoin = 1 Bitcoin, and that's it.

If you want historical market prices, you will have to either scrape them from various exchanges yourself, or use a service such as [this](https://www.cryptodatasets.com/platforms/Bitfinex/BTC/) (I have no affiliation with them, and just found them through Google - I cannot vouch for their data, and better options may exist).

Comment: Can you help with some exchanges that provide historical prices since the initial times of bitcoin? 
Most of the services, like CoinMarketCap (https://pro.coinmarketcap.com/api/v1#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsHistorical) are paid or provide history for a period of max 1 year!

Thanks! You really clarified most of the doubts!

Comment: @Harish : Service or product recommendations don't fit well with the design and purpose of this Q&A website and so are off-topic.

Comment: @HarishGupta I've never gone looking for historical data, so I can't make any recommendations, but it is my understanding that you either scrape it yourself, or pay for high quality data. No one really offers good datasets that large for free.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick No problem! I understand!

Comment: @RaghavSood Ok! Any method to scrape it?